# How to make a counter work over several requests?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, session-variables

I have this code

```
                if (empty($sid)) {
                    $sid = 0;
                } else {
                    $sid++;
                }

                $_SESSION['words'][$sid] = $try;
```

$sid nowhere else set in the script.

When i load that page the value of $sid stays at 0. It should increase.
I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: you must save sid value in a cookie or session and use that value to check.. :)

Comment: When page is load it goes in if cond. because its get $sid variable blank.So declare variable on top the page and check it

Comment: Here's whats the docs say: "Empty will return FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE." In your case since $sid doesn't exist `empty($sid)` will always return TRUE and the first part of your `if` condition gets executed, i.e `$sid = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are not preserved between requests. You can save `$sid` in the session as well.

```
            $sid = $_SESSION['sid'];
            if (empty($sid)) {
                $sid = 0;
            } else {
                $sid++;
            }
            $_SESSION['sid'] = $sid;
            $_SESSION['words'][$sid] = $try;
```

Comment: This will work as long as the session lives. If you want this counter to be more permanent, store it somewhere more permanent, like a database.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.. I did not thought of that ;)

Comment: :) Oh will do sorry, must hab forgotten the to click :)

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are not like the session or cookies, they are reset when the page reloads (each roundtrip).

Use the session or a cookie instead to store the `$sid` value.

Comment: I haven't down-voted but this must be comment and not answer.

Comment: It's not enough to be an answer and it has a lot of grammer/spelling errors.

Comment: my answer is use session or cookie instead. about grammar what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save value of `sid` in session or cookie then you can check like this :

Try to use `isset`

```
 $sid = $_SESSION['sid']; OR 
 $sid = $_COOKIE['sid'];

 if (isset($sid)) {
        $sid = 0;
 } else {
        $sid++;
 }

 $_SESSION['sid'] = $sid;
 $_SESSION['words'][$sid] = $try;
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: @Dr.Dan : I have tested it and then posted. Its working properly.

Comment: Yeah...still wrong. You are not storing the value in `$_SESSION['sid']`